# understanding pytorch conv2d internally

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, convolution

I'm trying to understand what does the nn.conv2d do internally.

so lets assume we are applying Conv2d to a 32*32 RGB image.

```
torch.nn.Conv2d(3, 49, 4, bias=True)
```

so :

1. when we initialize the conv layer how many weights and in which shapes would it have, please tell this for biases apart?
2. before applying it the conv the image would have 3 * 32 * 32 shape and after applying it would have 49 * 29 * 29 so what happens in between?

I define "slide" operation (don't know real name) as multiplying first to element of kernel to first element of box in shape of image going till last element of kernel corresponding making one the 1of29 * 1of29 is calculated.
and "slide all" doing this horizontally and vertically till the all 29 * 29 are calculated.

so I understand how a kernel would act but I don't understand how many kernels would be created by the `torch.nn.Conv2d(3, 49, 4, bias=True)` and which of them would be apllying on R,G,B channels.

Comment: see [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/intuitively-understanding-convolutions-for-deep-learning-1f6f42faee1)

Comment: @Shai thanx so I think the answer to my first question is 49*4*4 weights + 49 biases.

Comment: no as Ivan said 49*(4*4*3 + 1) would be the weights.

Comment: @FarhangAmaji Indeed 49*4*4*3 weights + 49 biases.

Comment: @Ivan I have another question which I have asked it in "cross validated" but they closed that, which it's unacceptable for me https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/543809/recommended-ways-of-splitting-train-test-in-time-series-in-neural-networks
because all alternative links which are provided are for cross validation not data splitting.

Comment: first of all aren't the data splitting and cross validation different? if so, so they shouldn't close it.

Comment: @FarhangAmaji This is a different question to *understanding pytorch conv2d internally*, the best is you create a new question on Stack Overflow with your problem.

Comment: I know I was just looking for a favor from you, and don't get me wrong, the favor is a short answer to "aren't the cross-validation and data splitting different ?" so I can decide whether to continue to try to reopen my question there or not, cause once my flag is declined? and as I think you would probably know the answer and the fact the cross validation is about having different models but data splitting is general and can be applied to one model no different ones.

Comment: unfortunately no ones gives reason to flags.

Comment: ofc I think Iam right but declining the flag made me dout about it.

Comment: Did you read the [proposed thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14099/using-k-fold-cross-validation-for-time-series-model-selection) they linked you?

Comment: kinda there are answers to cross validation I think, even the  Hyndman and Athanasopoulos way.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand how a kernel would act but I don't understand how many
> kernels would be created by the `nn.Conv2d(3, 49, 4, bias=True)` and
> which of them would be applying on R, G, and B channels.

Calling `nn.Conv2d(3, 49, 4, bias=True)` will initialize `49` `4x4`-kernels, each having a total of three channels and a single bias parameter. That's a total of `49*(4*4*3 + 1)` parameters, *i.e.* **2,401** parameters.

You can check that it is indeed correct with:

```
>>> conv2d = nn.Conv2d(3, 49, 4, bias=True)
```

Parameters list will contain the *weight* tensor shaped `(n_filters=49, n_channels=3, kernel_height=4, kernel_width=4)`, and a *bias* tensor shaped `(49,)`:

```
>>> [p.shape for p in conv2d.parameters()]
[torch.Size([49, 3, 4, 4]), torch.Size([49])]
```

If we get a look at the total number of parameters, we indeed find:

```
>>> nn.utils.parameters_to_vector(conv2d.parameters()).numel()
2401
```

Concerning how they are applied: each one of the `49` kernels will be applied 'independently' to the input map. For each filter operation, you are convolving the input of a three-channel tensor, with a three-channel kernel. Each one of those `49` convolutions gets its respective bias added. At the end, you are left with a number of `49` single-channel maps which are concatenated to make up a single `49`-channel map. In practice, everything is done in one go using a window view of the input.

<sub>I am certainly biased towards my own posts: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65554032/understanding-convolutional-layers-shapes/65612711#65612711) you will find another explanation of shapes in convolutional neural networks.</sub>